# Devise: How to redirect to the previous page after login, but only if previous page requires authentication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Using the [Devise](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise) gem, how can I redirect to the previous page after login, but only if the previous page requires authentication (otherwise redirect to a specific page I define)?

Required scenarios:

- Try to access `/my-private-account` > Devise detects authentication required and redirects to login > Successfully login > redirect to `/my-private-account`
- Visit `/` (doesn't require authentication) > visit `/login` > Successfully login > redirect to specific page eg. `/dashboard`
- Visit `/about` (doesn't require authentication) > visit `/login` > Successfully login > redirect to `/dashboard`

This is *almost* covered by the [Devise Wiki](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-back-to-current-page-after-sign-in,-sign-out,-sign-up,-update), but their answer redirects back for ALL pages. Eg. from `/` (doesn't require authentication) > visit `/login` > Successfully login > redirects back to `/`

My authentication is defined in routes:

```rb
# routes.rb
authenticate :user do
  resources :events
end
```

```rb
# application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :store_user_location!, if: :storable_location?

  private
    # Redirect back to current page after sign in
    # ref: https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-back-to-current-page-after-sign-in,-sign-out,-sign-up,-update
    def storable_location?
      request.get? && is_navigational_format? && !devise_controller? && !request.xhr? 
    end

    def store_user_location!
      # :user is the scope we are authenticating
      store_location_for(:user, request.fullpath)
    end

    def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
      stored_location_for(resource) || dashboard_path
    end

end
```

Is there a way I can check whether a route requires authentication? Then I could override `after_sign_in_path_for` eg.

```rb
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  if stored_location_for(resource).requires_authentication? # something like this...?
    stored_location_for(resource)
  else
    events_path
  end
end
```

Or am I tackling this in the wrong direction and is there a better way?

Lastly, is there anything else I need to be aware of to make this work for omniauth too?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you actually need to override is the `storable_location?` method so you don't store locations you don't want to go back.

For example, in the controller that handles the `/` or `/about` routes, you could override that `storable_location?` method to always return false so those locations are not stored, then `stored_location_for` won't be set.

Comment: Yes, this is a decent approach but do you know if there is a way I can do it programmatically? Ie. check all pages that do not require auth or that do require auth. Otherwise I will need to maintain a hardcoded list of pages which I want to avoid.

Comment: I guess you can play with `self.__callbacks` object to maybe get the configuration of `before_action` callbacks you have on a controller, but that code is too private, I wouldn't do that. Also I don't think you need to keep track of a list of hardcoded pages, you need to override that methods on the controllers you use `before_action :authenticate_user!` to return true and the rest return false I guess.

Comment: I agree that I don't think I want to play with the private methods. I don't set authenticate_user! on any controllers though. I define all authentication in my `routes.rb` file. Or does this still call authenticate_user! behind the scenes?

Comment: I see, no, it doesn't use `authenticate_user!` behind the scenes when using the router auth option, it redirect to the login page without even reaching the controller. You can still override the `storable_location?` method though, maybe the router has some methods to detect if a url requires authentication, I don't know sorry.